# When you get a computer what are the password for all the services like ftp, telnet, ssh by default

Tags: linux

I tried to break into my own ftp server but it didn't work, guess the word list was too limited.

Comment: It tends to be one of the users, like root, or not configured, at all. You need to configure the services.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. It's whatever password(s) you configured for user accounts on the system.